# Issues with passing a bunch of default values in a dictionary into the template

Tags: python, django

For a bunch of my views there were a lot of dictionary values that I was passing each time (along with the context_instance), so I tried to make a shortcut:

```
def render_with_context(request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['context_instance'] = RequestContext(request)
    kwargs['dict']['dare_count'] = Dare.objects.all().count()
    kwargs['dict']['proof_count'] = Proof.objects.all().count()
    kwargs['dict']['user_count'] = User.objects.all().count()
    return render_to_response(*args, **kwargs)
```

But it wont work, because django won't accept named dictionaries in the template, it only wants an annonymous {} dictionary. How should I go about fixing this, how is it possible to remove a name from a value?

Thanks

EDIT FIXED: (Using Han's suggestion of ** unpacking a dictionary)

## Notable changes: ['dict'] is gone, we just pass context_instance as an argument, the dictionary is not unpacked.

```
def render_with_context(request, args, kwargs):
   kwargs['dare_count'] = Dare.objects.all().count()
   kwargs['proof_count'] = Proof.objects.all().count()
   kwargs['user_count'] = User.objects.all().count()
   return render_to_response(args, kwargs, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a **named** dictionary vs an **anonymous** one. There isn't a concept like that in Python. A dictionary literal is exactly the same as any other dictionary.

Comment: Here is an example of how I use the method:    return render_with_context(request, 'home.html', dict={"rootURL" : getRootURL(), "stuff" : stuff, "stuff" : stuff, "stuff" : stuff}) The passed dictionary is named dict

Comment: You mean a named argument then. That has nothing to do with whether the dictionary is a literal. ``somefunc(dict={...})`` is exactly the same to python as ``somedict = {...}`` followed by ``somefunc(dict=somedict)``.

Comment: Well somefunc(dict={}) results in an error, while somefunc({}) dosen't

Comment: I think you are talking about *keyword arguments* and *positional arguments*. `method(argname=value)` is a keyword argument, `method(value)` is passing in a positional argument instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `render_to_response(template_name, kwargs)`. Render to response takes an actual dictionary as its argument, so you can reuse the dictionary `kwargs`. `**kwargs` unpacks the dictionary unto keyword style arguments, so it is no longer a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what my method is right now, except *args is actually template_name, I think the issue is my dictionary is named "dict" instead of being annonymous.

Comment: You nailed it man thank you! Didn't know that ** unpacked a dictionary, what does * do in *args? unpack a list?

Comment: `**kwargs` will not pass a dictionary, it will expand the values of the dictionary as keyword arguments, the call becomes `render_to_response('template_name`, context_instance=whatever, dare_count=something, etc)`. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: And yes `function(*args)` becomes `function(arg[0], arg[1] ... arg[n])`